# Addition 2 large number using stack in C language

Tags: c, stack, addition

Im trying to write a program for addition with large numbers using stack.
My steps include pushing string 1(the first number) into stack 1, pushing str2 into stack 2, doing the addition and pushing to the third stack (I also use variable 'carry' and them add it to the next sum). After that, I pop stack 3 to a string.
I dont know why my code just works well in some cases, for example, num1 = '123', num2 = '124'.
Thanks for helping me!

```
     #include<stdio.h>
     #include<string.h>
     #include<stdlib.h>
     #define MAX_LEN 100

     typedef struct stack{
       int top;
       unsigned length;
       char* arr;
     }Stack;

     Stack* makeNew(unsigned length){
      Stack* stack = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
      stack->length = length;
      stack->top = -1;
      stack->arr = (char*)malloc(stack->length * sizeof(char));
      return stack;
     }

     int isEmpty(Stack* stack){
       if(stack->top == -1) return 1;
       else return 0;
       }

       int isFull(Stack* stack){
           if(stack->top == stack->length - 1) return 1;
           else return 0;
       }

       void push(Stack* stack,char each_char){
           if(isFull(stack)){
            printf("Stack Overflow\n");
           }
           stack->arr[++stack->top] = each_char;
       }

       char pop(Stack* stack){
           if(isEmpty(stack)){
               printf("Stack Empty\n");
           }
           return stack->arr[stack->top--];
       }

       void swap(char *str1, char *str2){
         char *temp = (char *)malloc((strlen(str1) + 1) * sizeof(char));
         strcpy(temp, str1);
         strcpy(str1, str2);
         strcpy(str2, temp);
         free(temp);
       }

       void add(char str1[MAX_LEN],char str2[MAX_LEN]){
           char result[strlen(str1)];
           Stack* num1 = makeNew(strlen(str1));    
           Stack* num2 = makeNew(strlen(str2));
           Stack* stack = makeNew(strlen(str1));
           int i;
           for(i=0;i<strlen(str1);i++) push(num1,str1[i]);                          
           for(i=0;i<strlen(str2);i++) push(num2,str2[i]);

           int sum = 0;
           int carry = 0;

           for(i=0;i<strlen(str2);i++){
               sum = (pop(num1)-'0')+(pop(num2)-'0')+ carry;
               push(stack,sum%10 + '0');
               carry = sum/10;
           }
           for(i=strlen(str2);i<strlen(str1);i++){
               sum = (pop(num1)-'0') + carry;
               push(stack,sum%10 + '0');
               carry = sum/10;
           }
           if(carry>0) push(stack,carry);
                   //reverse the string

           for(i=0;i<strlen(str1);i++)
               result[i] = pop(stack);
           printf("The result is: %s",result);
       }

       int main(){
           char str1[MAX_LEN], str2[MAX_LEN];
           printf("Enter the first number: ");
           scanf("%s",&str1);
           printf("Enter the second number: ");
           scanf("%s",&str2);
           if((strlen(str1))<(strlen(str2))) swap(str1,str2);
           add(str1,str2);
           return 0;
       }
```

Comment: *"Thanks for helping me!"* - with *what* ? You never asked a question.

Comment: You are missing two skills: Use of a debugger and unit tests. The former allows you to step through your code and inspect the local state, much like `printf()` calls sprinkled over the code. The latter makes sure that you don't break one thing while fixing another. For a start, I'd suggest you learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: What are the cases when the program doesn't work?

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info, so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve the code to get no warnings. Then [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)

Comment: Also, read the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) of every function you are using (like `printf`, `malloc`, etc...). They could fail, and you generally should handle the failure case.

Comment: As @UlrichEckhardt says, you need some unit tests.  Easy way to start collecting those tests is to keep all the examples of where it fails.  Start fixing each failure one at a time but keep the code which caused it.  Then when you fix the next bug you still run the old tests to check you didn't break something.  Over time you get to build a respectable set of tests.

Answer (score 0):

This fixes the issue where the result is longer than the longest input string.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX_LEN 100

typedef struct stack{
    int top;
    unsigned length;
    char* arr;
}Stack;

Stack* makeNew(unsigned length) {
    Stack* stack = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    stack->length = length;
    stack->top = -1;
    stack->arr = (char*)malloc(stack->length * sizeof(char));
    return stack;
}

int isEmpty(Stack* stack)
{
    if(stack->top == -1) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

int isFull(Stack* stack)
{
    if(stack->top == stack->length - 1) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

void push(Stack* stack, char each_char)
{
    if(isFull(stack)) {
        printf("Stack Overflow\n");
    }
    stack->arr[++stack->top] = each_char;
}

char pop(Stack* stack)
{
    if(isEmpty(stack)) {
        printf("Stack Empty\n");
    }
    return stack->arr[stack->top--];
}

void swap(char *str1, char *str2)
{
    char *temp = (char *)malloc((strlen(str1) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(temp, str1);
    strcpy(str1, str2);
    strcpy(str2, temp);
    free(temp);
}

void add(char str1[MAX_LEN],char str2[MAX_LEN])
{
    int resultLength = strlen(str1)+1;
    char result[resultLength];

    Stack* num1 = makeNew(strlen(str1));    
    Stack* num2 = makeNew(strlen(str2));

    Stack* stack = makeNew(resultLength);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(str1); i++) push(num1,str1[i]);                          
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(str2); i++) push(num2,str2[i]);

    int sum = 0;
    int carry = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(str2); i++) {
        sum = (pop(num1) - '0') + (pop(num2) - '0') + carry;
        push(stack, sum % 10 + '0');
        carry = sum / 10;
    }

    for(i = strlen(str2); i < strlen(str1); i++) {
        sum = (pop(num1) - '0') + carry;
        push(stack, sum % 10 + '0');
        carry = sum / 10;
    }

    if(carry > 0) {
        push(stack, carry + '0');
    }

    //reverse the string
    for(i = 0; i < resultLength; i++) {
        result[i] = pop(stack);
    }
    printf("The result is: %s", result);
}

int main()
{
    char str1[MAX_LEN], str2[MAX_LEN];
    printf("Enter the first number: ");
    scanf("%s",&str1);
    printf("Enter the second number: ");
    scanf("%s",&str2);
    if((strlen(str1))<(strlen(str2))) swap(str1,str2);
    add(str1,str2);
    return 0;
}
```